# MSTest - Asserting a decimal is equal to another decimal - with a tolerance

Tags: c#, mstest

If I am verifying some calculations on a decimal type, and I want to assert that it is "close enough" to the expected value, I currently do this:

```
Assert.IsTrue(Math.Abs(17.0973M - actual) < 0.001M);
```

It works just fine, but is there a simpler or prettier way of expressing the same - which I have missed?

If I was comparing soemthing of type double, there is an option to assing a ```delta`` argument on Assert.AreEqual, which looks more elegant and expressive:

```
Assert.AreEqual(expcetedDouble, actualDouble, 0.00001);
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.equals?view=net-5.0

Comment: (describes epsilon calculations)

Comment: Fluent Assertions has `Should().BeApproximately()` for this purpose, which is available for `decimal`s too.

Comment: If MSTest's `Assert.AreEqual` has no appropriate overload for `decimal` maybe the cleanest way is to use a `TolerantEquals` extension: `Assert.IsTrue(17.0973m.TolerantEquals(actual, 0.001m))`. Just a bit simpler than the original expression, though.